# Entity framework 5 many to many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, orm

I have problem because when I add the following to class `Course` I have only 2 tables not 3

```
public int PersonId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PersonId")]
public virtual Person Student { get; set; }
```

you do not have these three lines all good, but I need an additional field in class Course

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesAttending { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Student { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Students { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SchoolContext>(
                new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SchoolContext>());

        SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();
        var cos = from d in db.Courses
                  select d;
    }
}
```

please help me

Comment: You have only defined 2 tables (`Courses` and `People`) to begin with.  I'm not sure where this 3rd table is coming from.

Comment: @48klocs: The third table is the join table for the many-to-many relationship that EF would detect by convention automatically if `Course.Student` is NOT in the model. With that property EF doesn't detect the many-to-many relation anymore and the third table disappears, so to speak...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF cannot decide if `Course.Student` or `Course.Students` refers to `Person.CoursesAttending`. You must give EF a hint, for example by using the `[InverseProperty]` attribute on `Course.Students`:

```
[InverseProperty("CoursesAttending")]
public virtual ICollection<Person> Students { get; set; }
```

**Edit**

The model will cause multiple cascading delete paths, namely: When you delete a `Person` records in the join table will be deleted as well, but it will also delete all `Course`s that this person is assigned to through the `Course.Person` property. The deleted `Course`s will delete records in the join table again which is the second delete path on the same table.

Multiple cascading delete paths are not allowed with SQL Server, so you must disable it with Fluent API:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    //...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Student)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.PersonId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add this code I have Error: Additional information: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.CoursePersons_dbo.People_Person_PersonId' on table 'CoursePersons' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: @user1644160: See my Edit. That will fix the error hopefully.

Comment: can you explain why you like .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)?

Comment: @Nikos: It is explained in the Edit section of my answer. SQL Server does not allow two cascading delete paths onto the same table, so you must disable at least one cascading delete which is what `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` does.